# Rank values in a row with QGIS field calculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, rank

I have a table with years and months like this
[image]

Using order by expression I can classify the first 5 years with the highest value, or in a specific month, classify the first 5 years with the highest value, but how do I classify in a specific year (2021) the first 5 months with the higher value?

In Excel this would be easily possible using ctrl+c, paste special transpose, putting table rows into columns and columns into rows

Like this

[image]

How do this on QGIS field calculator?

Comment: It's a good question, ordinarily my understanding is that the best approach would be to "unpivot" your data (i.e. have a row for each year-month combination, so row 1- 2022 January 157, row 2 - 2022 February 18, and so on) but this sort of presentation is common in spatial datasets when you want one geometry for a row. I had a think about using attributes() but it got too convoluted. I think Python might be the best approach for this.

Comment: I dont understand what result you want? Should the entiry table be sorted by the sum of the five highest values in each row? Or do you want to calculate a new column in each row?

Comment: I want to sort months in a year from highest value to lowest value

Comment: In excel this would be easily possible using ctrl+c, paste special transpose, putting table rows into columns and columns into rows.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my convoluted QGIS expression answer - but it only takes the top 5 as in it cuts off after #5, it cannot actually rank the numbers where there are duplicates. In which case, if your #5 position has two months with the same value, the result will only pick up one of them.

Replace `year` with the name of the column you don't want (`field_1` in your example).

```
array_foreach(
     array_sort(
      array_filter(
         array_foreach(map_akeys(map_delete(attributes(),'year')), 
                       array_find(
                          array_slice(
                             array_sort(
                                map_avals(map_delete(attributes(),'year'))
                                        ,0)
                                     ,0,4),
                                  eval(@element)) 
                        ||'@'||@element),
                     @element not ilike '-1%'),
                  0),
             regexp_substr(@element,'@(.+)'))
```

---

Example: CSV screenshot in Excel

[image]

Result: Attribute table in QGIS

[image]

Comment: I think if it possible change the table, were the lines are the months and columns are the year, it's possible classify by expression a specific year